# Can't Connect to Vbox Virtual Machine on my Ubuntu server via windows RDP

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, virtualization, virtualbox-networking

I have an ubuntu 18.x server. I installed virtualbox on the server and configured a new VM using [these instructions](https://websiteforstudents.com/create-virtualbox-guest-machines-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-server-headless/). When I try the last step I get an error window
[image]

I also noticed that when I run netstat, the IP associated with my VM's port is 0.0.0.0

But when I run `nmap` on my servers IP I get this

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
5001/tcp open  commplex-link
```

Where the last row is the port number of my VM
Here is the output of `$ VboxManage showvmdetails tails` (which is far more verbose than the tutorials example)

```
Name:                        tails
Groups:                      /
Guest OS:                    Linux 2.6 / 3.x / 4.x (32-bit)
UUID:                        7107a87f-4ffb-4c80-9cf9-0bc3ff6c6b4c
Config file:                 /var/vbox/tails/tails.vbox
Snapshot folder:             /var/vbox/tails/Snapshots
Log folder:                  /var/vbox/tails/Logs
Hardware UUID:               7107a87f-4ffb-4c80-9cf9-0bc3ff6c6b4c
Memory size                  1024MB
Page Fusion:                 disabled
VRAM size:                   8MB
CPU exec cap:                100%
HPET:                        disabled
CPUProfile:                  host
Chipset:                     piix3
Firmware:                    BIOS
Number of CPUs:              1
PAE:                         enabled
Long Mode:                   disabled
Triple Fault Reset:          disabled
APIC:                        enabled
X2APIC:                      enabled
Nested VT-x/AMD-V:           disabled
CPUID Portability Level:     0
CPUID overrides:             None
Boot menu mode:              message and menu
Boot Device 1:               DVD
Boot Device 2:               DVD
Boot Device 3:               HardDisk
Boot Device 4:               Not Assigned
ACPI:                        enabled
IOAPIC:                      disabled
BIOS APIC mode:              APIC
Time offset:                 0ms
RTC:                         local time
Hardw. virt.ext:             enabled
Nested Paging:               enabled
Large Pages:                 disabled
VT-x VPID:                   enabled
VT-x unr. exec.:             enabled
Paravirt. Provider:          Default
Effective Paravirt. Prov.:   KVM
State:                       running (since 2019-12-11T04:49:39.483000000)
Monitor count:               1
3D Acceleration:             disabled
2D Video Acceleration:       disabled
Teleporter Enabled:          disabled
Teleporter Port:             0
Teleporter Address:          
Teleporter Password:         
Tracing Enabled:             disabled
Allow Tracing to Access VM:  disabled
Tracing Configuration:       
Autostart Enabled:           disabled
Autostart Delay:             0
Default Frontend:            
Storage Controller Name (0):            tails_SATA
Storage Controller Type (0):            IntelAhci
Storage Controller Instance Number (0): 0
Storage Controller Max Port Count (0):  30
Storage Controller Port Count (0):      30
Storage Controller Bootable (0):        on
tails_SATA (0, 0): /tmp/tails-amd64-4.1.iso (UUID: b48d5261-170d-4bc8-a1d6-2ee18c29051f)
tails_SATA (1, 0): /var/box/tails.vdi (UUID: 94e4ba64-b33d-4cdf-a37f-959ccd3dcffb)
NIC 1:                       MAC: 080027B4FB40, Attachment: NAT, Cable connected: on, Trace: off (file: none), Type: 82540EM, Reported speed: 0 Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: deny, Bandwidth group: none
NIC 1 Settings:  MTU: 0, Socket (send: 64, receive: 64), TCP Window (send:64, receive: 64)
NIC 2:                       disabled
NIC 3:                       disabled
NIC 4:                       disabled
NIC 5:                       disabled
NIC 6:                       disabled
NIC 7:                       disabled
NIC 8:                       disabled
Pointing Device:             PS/2 Mouse
Keyboard Device:             PS/2 Keyboard
UART 1:                      disabled
UART 2:                      disabled
UART 3:                      disabled
UART 4:                      disabled
LPT 1:                       disabled
LPT 2:                       disabled
Audio:                       enabled (Driver: ALSA, Controller: AC97, Codec: STAC9700)
Audio playback:              disabled
Audio capture:               disabled
Clipboard Mode:              disabled
Drag and drop Mode:          disabled
Session name:                headless
Video mode:                  720x400x0 at 0,0 enabled
VRDE:                        enabled (Address 0.0.0.0, Ports 5001, MultiConn: off, ReuseSingleConn: off, Authentication type: null)
VRDE port:                   5001
Video redirection:           disabled
VRDE property               : TCP/Ports  = "5001"
VRDE property               : TCP/Address = <not set>
OHCI USB:                    disabled
EHCI USB:                    disabled
xHCI USB:                    disabled

USB Device Filters:

<none>

Available remote USB devices:

<none>

Currently Attached USB Devices:

<none>

Bandwidth groups:  <none>

Shared folders:<none>

VRDE Connection:             not active
Clients so far:              0

Capturing:                   not active
Capture audio:               not active
Capture screens:             
Capture file:                /var/vbox/tails/tails.webm
Capture dimensions:          1024x768
Capture rate:                512kbps
Capture FPS:                 25kbps
Capture options:             

Guest:

Configured memory balloon size: 0MB
OS type:                     Linux26
Additions run level:         0

Guest Facilities:

No active facilities.
```

How can I fix this to connect to my VM via RDP?
I really Just don't know where to even start. I'm a software developer, and normally I can extrapolate some information from errors, but this doesn't tell me anything. Is the problem in the server side? on the host side? my network configuration? the virtual box setup? my Windows permissions? I'm all over the place trying to find a path to follow. I don't know enough about networking so I am here for help. I've posted on Superuser and Serverfault as well and received no responses whatsoever

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem following [the guide](https://websiteforstudents.com/create-virtualbox-guest-machines-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-server-headless/) you used. Did the following to fix the problem:

---

enable multi-connection

```
sudo VBoxManage modifyvm ubuntu16 --vrdemulticon on
```

allow port 5001

```
sudo ufw allow 5001/tcp
```

reboot

```
sudo VBoxManage controlvm ubuntu16 savestate
sudo reboot
sudo VBoxManage startvm ubuntu16 --type headless
```

finally, can open Microsoft Remote Desktop to enter IP address and port

```
PC name: 192.107.123.12:5001
```

[a screenshot of connecting to Remote Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1mUV.png)

The above worked for me on a Ubuntu 18.04 server with Virtual Box 5.2.44. Think should also work on Ubuntu 16.04 with Virtual Box 6.1.

Hope it can be of any help!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you are using an old, buggy version of vbox extension pack. You will have tho update the same. [Here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) is the link to the page to download it.

[image: download page]

Comment: Might be a noob question but what do I do with the download? It's just a binary. Where do I put it?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. Unfortunately I can't install it for some reason. Throws error. And when I try to uninstall the old one it says it uninstalled succesfully but `VBoxManage extpack list` says it's still there?